# Store data at client browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, browser

I have a scenario for some data need to store at client side I dont want to use server memory. I need to store data like resultset.

For exmp I have shopping site and when the user is to do add to basket I need to store that basket information to the browser cookie.

In short I need to store a list object in the web browser cookie.

I had use the cookie but it only store the string object.

I think the problem can be solve by serialize the list object to json string or xml string but I didnt get the right way for the same.

Can any one suggest me a right way to achive this.

I most appriciate your solution.

Comment: cookies, or [web storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage). pick your poison.

Comment: Depending on what browsers you need to support options such as Web SQL and Indexed DB are available. You'll need to refine your question somewhat for specific answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), but it is limited to 5mb and not supported by IE7 and less.

Alternatively, for cross-browser compatibility you can use 3rd party libraries like [Store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/).

Comment: But how can I access the local storage data to the server side

Comment: You want be able to access your localStorage from server-side. Only you can do is to send that to your server, e.g with ajax request. If you need access that data without any action from client the best way will be storing that data on server.

Comment: The store.js is actually uses cookies or other stuff I need to get at the httocontext for each request